# Deploy shiny app that can call runApp() inside application itself (specifically for tabulizer package)

Tags: r, shiny, tabulizer

I'm trying to deploy a Shiny app that allows the user to upload a pdf document and extract a table from a selected page. For this I'm using the package `tabulizer`. A basic reproducible example:

```
library(shiny)
library(tabulizer)

ui <- fluidPage(
  fileInput("report", NULL,buttonLabel = "Upload report"),
  numericInput("page","Specify page number",value = 1),
  actionButton("extract","Extract"),
  verbatimTextOutput("data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  generate_data <- reactive({
    req(input$report)
    # This locate_area function calls runApp() from the tabulizer package
    area <- locate_areas(file = input$report$datapath,
                         pages = input$page, 
                         widget = "reduced")  
    table <- extract_tables(file = input$report$datapath,
                            pages = input$page,
                            area = area)
    return(table)
  })%>% bindCache(input$page) %>% bindEvent(input$extract)
  
  output$data <- renderPrint({
    # Just for the sake of this example to show it works
    generate_data()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If I run this locally, the `locate_area()` will make the pdf page pop-up on my viewer in RStudio and all is well. However, if I publish the app it doesn't run after clicking the action button. I know the problem comes from the `locate_area()` as it essentially calls another `runApp` within the shiny app. I have tried using different widgets for `locate_area()` to no avail. Does anybody know a way to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the relevant issues - [issue 15](https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer/issues/15) and [issue 53](https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer/issues/53) - it appears that your best way to go is really to copy the functionality from the original `tabulizer` function into your own app, as currently the package does not provide an easy integration with other Shiny apps.